# In same test plan how to run parallel and sequential thread groups in Jmeter

Tags: automation, jmeter, performance-testing, jmx

My test plan in jmeter is

`Test Plan
  Thread Group1
  Thread Group2
  Thread Group3`

Intailly I want to run Thread Group1 then after finshing it I need to start both Thread Group2 & Thread Group3 parallely. Here I cannot use shedulers as i dont know how long it will take to finsh Thread Group1
Appreciated your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is why JMeter has [SetUp Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group):

> A special type of ThreadGroup that can be utilized to perform Pre-Test Actions. The behavior of these threads is exactly like a normal Thread Group element. The difference is that these type of threads execute before the test proceeds to the executing of regular Thread Groups.

So change *Thread Group1* into a `SetUp Thread Group` type, and then let *Thread Group2* and *Thread Group3* to run on parallel:

```
Test Plan (Run Thread Groups Consecutively is unchecked)
  setUp Thread Group (formerly Thread Group1)
  Thread Group2
  Thread Group3
```